# F# Codewars Integers: Recreation Two

Tags: f#

Trying to solve [task](https://www.codewars.com/kata/integers-recreation-two) with

**Code**

```
open System

let rec distribute e = function
  | [] -> [[e]]
  | x::xs' as xs -> (e::xs)::[for xs in distribute e xs' -> x::xs]

let rec permute = function
  | [] -> [[]]
  | e::xs -> List.collect (distribute e) (permute xs)

let MoreRule (a: int) (b: int) (c: int) (d: int) = 
    let permutations = permute [a;b;c;d]
    let sums = permutations |> List.map(fun x -> x.[0]*x.[1] + x.[2]*x.[3])
    let diffs = permutations |> List.map(fun x -> x.[0]*x.[1] - x.[2]*x.[3])
    List.append sums diffs
    |> List.distinct
    |> List.filter(fun x -> x>0)
    |> List.sort

let factor number list = [
    for i in list do 
        let t = Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt((number-Math.Pow((float)i,2.0)))) |> int
        if (List.exists ((=)t) list) then 
            yield [|i;t|]
    ]

let prod2Sum (a: int) (b: int) (c: int) (d: int): int[] list = 
    let number = (float)(((a*a)+(b*b))*((c*c)+(d*d)))   
    let coefficients = MoreRule a b c d
    factor number coefficients
    |> List.map(fun arr -> if (arr.[0]>arr.[1]) then [|arr.[1];arr.[0]|] else [|arr.[0];arr.[1]|])
    |> List.distinct
```

When clicking on Attemp button on page i get response Failed Exit Code 1

> Expected: [[|75; 104|]; [|85; 96|]] Actual: []

But on my local PC `prod2Sum 4 5 20 1` return proper result `[[|75; 104|]; [|85; 96|]]`

The main question what I am doing wrong? How to improve this code? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not exactly know what is wrong with your code - to help with that, you probably need to explain more about how it is supposed to work - but I was able to replicate the case for which your code fails. If you run your `prod2Sum` function as follows, then it returns an empty list:

```
prod2Sum 1 20 -4 -5
```

The expected result by CodeWars is `[[|75; 104|]; [|85; 96|]]`. I did not figure out how your code is trying to solve the problem, but some experimentation suggests that negative values get filtered out in `MoreRule` by the following line:

```
|> List.filter(fun x -> x > 0)
```

Removing this does not quite work - I get the right numbers, but some are negative. Replacing this with `List.map abs` works in this example, but fails for some other inputs.

For the record, an easy way to find what's going wrong is to add some logging to your `prod2Sum` function:

```
let prod2Sum (a: int) (b: int) (c: int) (d: int): int[] list = 
    let number = (float)(((a*a)+(b*b))*((c*c)+(d*d)))   
    let coefficients = MoreRule a b c d
    let res = 
        factor number coefficients
        |> List.map(fun arr -> if (arr.[0]>arr.[1]) then [|arr.[1];arr.[0]|] else [|arr.[0];arr.[1]|])
        |> List.distinct
    if res = [] then 
        printfn "%A" (a,b,c,d) // Log inputs for which we returned wrong result
    r
```

With this, you should be able to find out what other test cases are failing.